# Using Google Map in iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I am beginner to iPhone application.
I want to know the way of using Goole Map.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Google maps are built-in in standard API provided by Apple. Have a look at [MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) framework that provides access to maps.